# Return to sheet where button was pushed

Tags: excel, vba

I have the following macro that selects cell A3 in every sheet:

```
Sub test ()
Sheet1.Select
Range("A3").Select
Sheet2.Select
Range("A3").Select
Sheet3.Select
Range("A3").Select
End Sub
```

In each of the sheets I have a button that is linked to this macro.
If you are in sheet2 and you click on the button in every sheet 
the cell A3 will be selected and in the end you will be in sheet3 although
you pushed the button in sheet2 since the macro ends with sheet3.

However, I want that once the macro did run you are in the sheet in which you pushed the button. Do you have any idea how to solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check this

```
Sub test()
Dim sht_name As String
sht_name = ActiveSheet.Name
Sheet1.Select
Range("A3").Select
Sheet2.Select
Range("A3").Select
Sheet3.Select
Range("A3").Select
Sheets(sht_name).Activate
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Sub test()
strME = Application.ActiveSheet.Name

Sheet1.Select
Range("A3").Select
Sheet2.Select
Range("A3").Select
Sheet3.Select
Range("A3").Select

Application.Sheets(strME).Select

End Sub
```